# oracle multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I achieve the following in oracle ?

```
       COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
ROW1   A          C                         
ROW2         B          D
```

desired result

```
       COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
ROW1   A     B     C    D
```

Comment: Hint: Group by, MAX.

Comment: what should happen if there are more rows? how do you decide ROW1 and ROW2 should be joined? what if ROW2 has a value in COL1 too? What.... Please update your post and try to describe exactly what you're going to achieve

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `MIN()` and `MAX()`. Let's call your table `mytable` and column with entries `ROW1` ,`ROW2` as `col2`

```
select MIN(col0) col0, MAX(col1) col1, MAX(col2) col2, 
       MAX(col3) col3, MAX(col4) col4 FROM mytable;
```

**Output:**

```
       COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4

ROW1    A    B    C    D
```

***Note***: This solution is not a general method to accomplish outputs like these and depends on the data.It works for this particular case.

Comment: not working, thanks for all

Comment: what is not working?. Your data is other than what you have shown in your question. You need to change the query accordingly.